# Magento - getCustomer() giving unexpected results

Tags: php, magento

I am experiencing some odd results when using Magento's

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

I have the below code to first check if the customer is logged in, and if so to get the firstname of the logged in customer:

```
if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
{
    $name = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
    print 'Hello '.$name;
    // ...
}
```

Most of the time this works fine and if `Joe Bloggs` is logged in then it outputs:

```
Hello Joe
```

But every now and then, and it seems to be when a high amount of customers are logged in I get unexpected outputs with other names

```
Hello Lucy 
or
Hello John
```

Is `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()` a foolproof way of getting the customers details or is it possible it's getting another logged in customers details? Or have I got a problem with my sessions mixing up?

Answer (score 0):

As per the core code in `Mage_Customer_Model_Session::getCustomer`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve customer model object
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    if ($this->_customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
        return $this->_customer;
    }

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    if ($this->getId()) {
        $customer->load($this->getId());
    }

    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    return $this->_customer;
}
```

...there's no way that another customer's data could be loaded (by core Magento).

It would firstly return the customer model if it's already loaded, if not then load it if there's an ID present already, and finally it would return an empty customer model if nothing else.

It's possible that your sessions are getting mixed up. I suggest you check your configuration - are you using databases, files, Redis etc for session storage?

Comment: Thanks, having looked into this more it was down to the full page cache on my store. A mix of making the relevant pages non-cached or hole punching blocks it now seems to have down the trick